# fscanf(). Read a file with a pattern in C

Tags: c, file, pattern-matching, scanf

I must read a txt file using `scanf` and show in console the content. It is neccesary doing that with `scanf`. Also `#`lines should be ommited on the output.

I have next txt file:

```
# Lista ciudades

Coruña, Vigo, Valladolid, Oviedo, Bilbao, Zaragoza, Gerona, Barcelona, Madrid, Badajoz, Albacete, Valencia, Murcia, Jaén, Sevilla, Granada, Cádiz


# Distancias entre ciudades

Coruña Vigo 171
Coruña Valladolid 455
Vigo Valladolid 356
Valladolid Bilbao 280
Valladolid Madrid 193
Oviedo Bilbao 304
Bilbao Madrid 395
Bilbao Zaragoza 324
Madrid Zaragoza 325
Zaragoza Barcelona 296
Barcelona Gerona 100
Valencia Barcelona 349
Madrid Badajoz 403
Madrid Jaén 335
Madrid Albacete 251
Albacete Valencia 191
Albacete Murcia 150
Murcia Granada 284
Murcia Valencia 241
Granada Jaén 99
Granada Sevilla 256
Jaén Sevilla 242
Sevilla Cádiz 125
```

Desired output is:

```
Coruña Vigo Valladolid Oviedo Bilbao Zaragoza Gerona Barcelona Madrid Badajoz Albacete Valencia Murcia Jaén Sevilla Granada Cádiz

Coruña Vigo 171
Coruña Valladolid 455
Vigo Valladolid 356
Valladolid Bilbao 280
Valladolid Madrid 193
Oviedo Bilbao 304
Bilbao Madrid 395
Bilbao Zaragoza 324
Madrid Zaragoza 325
Zaragoza Barcelona 296
Barcelona Gerona 100
Valencia Barcelona 349
Madrid Badajoz 403
Madrid Jaén 335
Madrid Albacete 251
Albacete Valencia 191
Albacete Murcia 150
Murcia Granada 284
Murcia Valencia 241
Granada Jaén 99
Granada Sevilla 256
Jaén Sevilla 242
Sevilla Cádiz 125
```

For achieving that, I was thinking in something like:

```
contadorAlmoadillas = 0;
if ((fichero = fopen("./files/carreteras.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
    // If contadorAlmoadillas is 1
    while (fscanf(fichero, " %[^,]",buffer) != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", buffer);
    }
    // If contadorAlmoadillas is 2
    while (fscanf(fichero, " %[^ ], %[^ ], %[^\n]",buffer1,buffer2,&d) != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s %i \n", buffer1,buffer2,d);
    }
    fclose(fichero);
}
```

But I am not getting desired output. It is due to scanf pattern.

Also, I do now know how can I count how many times appear `#` character, so I cant implement the if statement.

Any idea how can I do that?.

Thank you.

Comment: The pattern should be `$[^,\n]` otherwise it will read a token that goes across multiple lines.

Comment: Reading until `fscanf()` returns `NULL` will go until the end of the file. You can't use `scanf()` like that to stop at the end of the first line.

Comment: I usually recommend to `fgets()` the whole line and then pick it apart with what `<string.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` have to offer...

Comment: I don't think this task can be done using just `scanf()`.

Comment: I always used fgets for doing that. But it is a requisite using `scanf`... So I can not do that with fgets

Comment: I have achieved that, I will post the code if you wanna try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved my purpose. I have got it like:

```
// WAY 1
            int contadorAlmoadillas = 0;
            int contadorCamposLinea = 0;

            if ((fichero = fopen("./files/carreteras.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
                while (fscanf(fichero, " %[^,\n ]%*c",buffer) != EOF) {
                    G:
                    if (buffer[0] == '#') {
                        fscanf(fichero, " %[^\n]",buffer);
                        printf("\n\n\n# %s \n\n", buffer); // CABECERA
                        contadorAlmoadillas++;
                    } else {
                        // # Lista ciudades
                        if (contadorAlmoadillas == 1) {
                            printf("%s ", buffer); // CIUDAD
                        // # Distancias entre ciudades
                        } else if (contadorAlmoadillas == 2) {
                            if (contadorCamposLinea < 3) {
                                printf("%s ", buffer); // NODO1 Y NODO2 Y PESO
                                contadorCamposLinea++;
                            } else {
                                printf("\n");
                                contadorCamposLinea = 0;
                                goto G;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                printf("\n\n\n");
                fclose(fichero);
            }

// WAY 2
            int contadorAlmoadillas = 0;
            int contadorCamposLinea = 0;

            if ((fichero = fopen("./files/carreteras.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
                while (fscanf(fichero, " %[^,\n ]%*c",buffer) != EOF) {
                    if (buffer[0] == '#') {
                        fscanf(fichero, " %[^\n]",buffer);
                        printf("\n\n\n# %s \n\n", buffer); // CABECERA
                        contadorAlmoadillas++;
                    } else {
                        // # Lista ciudades
                        if (contadorAlmoadillas == 1) {
                            printf("%s ", buffer); // CIUDAD
                        // # Distancias entre ciudades
                        } else if (contadorAlmoadillas == 2) {
                            if (contadorCamposLinea < 2) {
                                printf("%s ", buffer); // NODO1 Y NODO2
                                contadorCamposLinea++;
                            } else {
                                printf("%s\n", buffer); // PESO
                                contadorCamposLinea = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                fclose(fichero);
            }
```

Both ways are equal, one using TAGs and other avoiding it. I hope it could be helpful for anyone more.

Regards.